# Snapchat identity theft

Tags: identity-theft

Someone has created a fake Snapchat account using my exact name. They added several of my friends and sent them snapchats using pictures of me from my instagram account . How can I find the orientation of the account ?

Comment: Report this account to the service provider: https://support.snapchat.com/en-US/i-need-help

Answer (score 2):

As [rook](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/975/rook) said, you should report the fake account to the service provider.

Apart from that I would suggest that you read [this](https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/protecting-yourself-social-networks) little article about social networking site privacy. Then, consider protecting yourself against similar incidents in the futureby [Improving your privacy on social media](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/news/online-privacy/how-to-improve-your-privacy-and-security-on-social-media).

Since you've mentions images from your Instagram account were used, consider [securing your Instagram account](https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/essential-guide-instagram/).